# USB Device manufacturer name in Windows API

Tags: usb, winapi

How can I get USB device manufacturer name through Win32 API.

I am looking for an example in Win32 API, not in .Net.

USB Device manufacturer name is embedded in USB descriptor.

Thanks

Comment: For USB HID devices you use the function HidD_GetManufacturerString from the Windows DDK.

Comment: Have you tried looking at SetupAPI?

Answer (score 2):

hi I think WMI can give the all information which u need from the windows
just fire query against the API 
it return all info available in the machine to you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186146%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: This example is specific to .Net. Do you know how can I do similar kind of work through Win32 API ?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain manufacturer name of the device by using "**SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty**" winapi.

Please refer the MSDN  [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551967(v=vs.85).aspx) for more details.

## Example code :

```
if ( SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, &spDevInfoData,SPDRP_MFG, &DataT, (PBYTE)bufManufact, sizeof(bufManufact), &nSize) ) 
{
} 
else 
{
    _tcscpy_s(bufManufact,sizeof(bufManufact)/sizeof(TCHAR),_T("Unknown"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the USBView sample which comes with the WDK to get the manufacturer name and other information about the USB devices.